# How to remove the final line of \nocite in latex

Tags: bibliographies, abnt, abntex2

everyone, i hope you're ok in this begin of 2021,

Well, i have a couple doubts about reference section on latex (overleaf)

1. How to align to left the reference tittle?
2. Is this possible to remove the "Nenhuma citação no texto." on final part of reference iten (image bellow)?

[image]

Update:

```
\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,                   % tamanho da fonte
    openright,              % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    oneside,                    % para impressão em verso e anverso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,                    % tamanho do papel. 
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    %chapter=TITLE,         % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %section=TITLE,         % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsection=TITLE,      % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,   % títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    english,                    % idioma adicional para hifenização
    %french,                    % idioma adicional para hifenização
    %spanish,               % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil                  % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}

% ---------------------
% Pacotes OBRIGATÓRIOS
% ---------------------
%\usepackage{lmodern}               % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
%\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}  %margens
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfont}{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % fonte do arquivo
\renewcommand{\ABNTEXchapterfontsize}{\Large} % fonte do título
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{lastpage}               % Usado pela Ficha catalográfica
\usepackage{indentfirst}            % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{color}                  % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Inclusão de gráficos \usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{figs}              % path das figuras
\usepackage{epsfig,subfig}          % Inclusão de figuras
\usepackage{microtype}              % Melhorias de justificação
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter} % remove o número do capítulo das equações
%\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}  % add the chapter number
% ---------------------

% ---------------------
% Pacotes ADICIONAIS
% ---------------------

%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}  % Comandos matemáticos avançados 
%\usepackage{setspace}                      % Para permitir espaçamento simples, 1 1/2 e duplo
%\singlespacing   %Para um espaçamento simples
%\onehalfspacing  %Para um espaçamento de 1,5
%\DoubleSpacing   %Para um espaçamento duplo. DS maísculos para esse tido de doc
\usepackage{verbatim}                   % Para poder usar o ambiente "comment"
\usepackage{tabularx}                   % Para poder ter tabelas com colunas de largura auto-ajustável
\usepackage{afterpage}                  % Para executar um comando depois do fim da página corrente
\usepackage{url}                        % Para formatar URLs (endereços da Web)
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}       % Para sinal (-) nos números.
\usepackage{soul, soulutf8}             % gerar marcador de texto
\usepackage{float}                      % pra gerir a posição dos gráficos e tabelas
\usepackage{multirow}                   % mult linhas nas tabelas
\usepackage{threeparttable}             % tabelas com 3 partes
\usepackage[textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}                   % altera a fonte do título
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont}    % remove o negrito de seções
%\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{caption,multicol,booktabs,array}

% ---------------------

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % ajusta o quadros e tabelas
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % negrito nas legendas
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false % <-- important
]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow} % permite que as legendas fiquem na parte superiro de quadros e tabelas



\newcommand{\quadroname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\listofquadrosname}{Lista de quadros}

\newfloat{quadro}{loq}{\quadroname}
\setfloatadjustment{quadro}{\centering}
\newlistof{listofquadros}{loq}{\listofquadrosname}
\newlistentry{quadro}{loq}{0}
\renewcommand{\cftquadroname}{\quadroname\space} 
\renewcommand{\cftquadroaftersnum}{\hfill\textendash\hfill}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{quadro}{htbp}{loq}
\floatname{quadro}{Quadro}
%\newcommand{\listofquadros}{\listof{quadro}{Lista de Quadros}}
\captionsetup[quadro]{listformat=simple}
%\usepackage{natbib}

%\usepackage{newfloat} % lista de quadros
%\PrepareListOf{quadro}{%
%\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Quadro~}}
% Corrigindo para que apareça o nome Quadro ao invés de Figura
%\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
%fileext=loq,
%listname={Lista de Quadros},
%name=Quadro,
%placement=p,
%within=section,
%chapterlistsgaps=off
%]{quadro}
% ---------------------
% Pacotes de CITAÇÕES
% ---------------------
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}    % Paginas com as citações na bibl
%\usepackage[alf, abnt-emphasize=bf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}               % Citações padrão ABNT (alfa)
%\usepackage[num]{abntex2cite}              % Citações padrão ABNT (numericas)
\usepackage{endnotes}
%\let \footnote=\endnote 
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering every new chapter
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Notas}
%\usepackage{pagenote}
%\makepagenote
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ---------------------


% Configurações de CITAÇÕES para abntex2
\include{extras/conf_citacoes}

% Inclusão de dados para CAPA e FOLHA DE ROSTO (título, autor, orientador, etc.)
\include{extras/dados}

% Inclui Configurações de aparência do PDF Final
\include{extras/conf_pdf}

% O tamanho da identação do parágrafo é dado por:
\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

% Controle do espaçamento entre um parágrafo e outro:
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % tente também \onelineskip

% ---------------------
% Compila o índice
% ---------------------
\makeindex
% ---------------------



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  INICIO DO DOCUMENTO  %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    
    % Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
    \frenchspacing
    
    % ----------------------------------------------------------
    % ELEMENTOS PRÉ-TEXTUAIS (Capa, Resumo, Abstract, etc.)
    % ----------------------------------------------------------
    \pretextual
    
    % Capa
    \include{pretextual/capa}
    
    % Folha de rosto (o * indica que haverá a ficha bibliográfica)
    %\imprimirfolhaderosto*
    
    
    
    % Imprimir Ficha Catalográfica
    \include{pretextual/catalografica}
    
    % Inserir Folha de Aprovação
    \include{pretextual/assinaturas}
    
    % Dedicatória
    \include{pretextual/dedicatorias}
    
    % Agradecimentos
    \include{pretextual/agradecimentos}
    
    % Epígrafe
    \include{pretextual/epigrafe}
    
    % Resumo e Abstract
    \include{pretextual/resumos}
    
    % Lista de ilustrações
    \pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
    \listoffigures*
    \cleardoublepage
    
    % Lista de quadros
    \pdfbookmark[0]{\listofquadrosname}{log}
    \listofquadros*
    \cleardoublepage
    
    % Lista de tabelas
    \pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
    \listoftables*
    \cleardoublepage
    
%   % Lista de Abreviaturas e Siglas
    \begin{siglas}
        \item[DSGE]  Dynamic Stochastic General Equilibrium
        \item[SFC]  Stock Flow Consistent
%       
%       
    \end{siglas}
    
    % Lista de símbolos
    \begin{simbolos}
      \item[$ \Gamma $] Letra grega Gama
      \item[$ \Lambda $] Lambda
      \item[$ \zeta $] Letra grega minúscula zeta
      \item[$ \in $] Pertence
    \end{simbolos}
    
    % Inserir o SUMÁRIO
    \pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
    \tableofcontents*
    \cleardoublepage
    
    % ----------------------------------------------------------
    % ELEMENTOS TEXTUAIS (Capítulos)
    % ----------------------------------------------------------
    \textual
    % Elementos textuais com numeração arábica
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    % Reinicia a contagem do número de páginas
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    
%\DoubleSpacing % espaçamento para esse tipo de documento

\include{capitulos/cap1_introducao}

\include{capitulos/cap2_ref}

\include{capitulos/cap3_met}

\include{capitulos/cap4_discussao}

\include{capitulos/cap5_conclusoes}
    
% ----------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS PÓS-TEXTUAIS (Referências, Glossário, Apêndices)
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\postextual

% Referências bibliográficas
%Uncomment the following two lines if you want to have a bibliography
%\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{ref.bib}


% Glossário (Consulte o manual)
%\glossary

% Apêndices
%\include{postextual/apendices}

% Anexos
\include{postextual/anexos}

% Índice remissivo (Consultar manual)
%\phantompart
%\printindex
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: We would need more than just a screen shot of the code you use. Can you provide code that replicates this behaviour? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. We call this a complete, minimal working example. Can you do that?

Comment: I've made a update.

Comment: Can you make the code more *minimal* so that is replicates *just* the behaviour that is needed? Also note that we don't have the separate files you `\include`, or even your `ref.bib`. For reference, see [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: Since you are using the BibTeX-based `abntex2cite` package and not `biblatex`, I have retagged your question. (Overleaf also didn't appear to be relevant, so I removed that tag as well. If Overleaf does play a more important role than just being your editor of choice, please highlight that in the question.) Please note that it is normally preferable to ask only one question per question: You could separate the question about the title and the question about "Nenhuma citação no texto" into two separate questions. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864